# Understanding spherical harmonics code

Tags: 3d, spherical-harmonics

I am trying to understand the function [computeColorFromSH](https://github.com/graphdeco-inria/diff-gaussian-rasterization/blob/main/cuda_rasterizer/forward.cu#L20), which is a part of the differentiable gaussian rasterizer used by the paper [3D Gaussian Splatting for Real-Time Radiance Field Rendering](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.04079).

I am looking for the formula that the code is based on. Here's an excerpt for the `degree > 2` part:

```
            result = result +
                SH_C3[0] * y * (3.0f * xx - yy) * sh[9] +
                SH_C3[1] * xy * z * sh[10] +
                SH_C3[2] * y * (4.0f * zz - xx - yy) * sh[11] +
                SH_C3[3] * z * (2.0f * zz - 3.0f * xx - 3.0f * yy) * sh[12] +
                SH_C3[4] * x * (4.0f * zz - xx - yy) * sh[13] +
                SH_C3[5] * z * (xx - yy) * sh[14] +
                SH_C3[6] * x * (xx - 3.0f * yy) * sh[15];
```

It seems to be some kind of polynomial. The Wikipedia article on Spherical Harmonics has only integrals, so I'm guessing that this is a special case and maybe even a well-known one.

Is anyone familiar with this? Where I can read more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this out ([the appendix of PlenOctree, Section B.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.14024.pdf)), since the SH implementation of 3D GS is directly borrowed from PlenOctree. I can walk you through it with an example. First, take a look at the real form of SH (I won't use Latex here since, you know it's painful):
[image]
Where $P_l^{|m|}(\cdot)$ is the [associative Legendre Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials):
[image]

(From Wikipedia)

So where are those `SH_C3`? They have some thing to do with:
$$
K_{lm} = \sqrt{\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}\frac{(l - |m|)!}{(l+|m|)!}}
$$
Ok, so basically, we first get $\theta$ and $\phi$, as the direction $(x, y, z)$ can be easily converted to the spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$. Therefore, the corresponding $\cos(\cdot), \sin(\cdot)$ values can be obtained.

Then we use the formula of associative Legendre Polynomial to get, say $m=0, l = 0$ case:
$$
P_0^0=1
$$
We next evaluate SH basis function (given in the first image), for example: $Y_{00}, l=0,m=0$ will be $\sqrt{1 / 4\pi} \approx 0.282095$, which equals to  `SH_C0` in the code. Other coefficients can be derived similarly: substitute $l, m$ with the order you need, then evaluate the whole formula and store the constant part. With all the precomputed coefficients, now you can multiply your learned SH coefficients with these precomputed ones. Hope this will help.